# Why is matrix multiplication faster with numpy than with ctypes in Python?

Tags: python, c, benchmarking, matrix-multiplication

I was trying to figure out the fastest way to do matrix multiplication and tried 3 different ways:

- Pure python implementation: no surprises here.
- Numpy implementation using `numpy.dot(a, b)`
- Interfacing with C using `ctypes` module in Python.

This is the C code that is transformed into a shared library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void matmult(float* a, float* b, float* c, int n) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    /*float* c = malloc(nay * sizeof(float));*/

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int sub = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                sub = sub + a[i * n + k] * b[k * n + j];
            }
            c[i * n + j] = sub;
        }
    }
    return ;
}
```

And the Python code that calls it:

```
def C_mat_mult(a, b):
    libmatmult = ctypes.CDLL("./matmult.so")

    dima = len(a) * len(a)
    dimb = len(b) * len(b)

    array_a = ctypes.c_float * dima
    array_b = ctypes.c_float * dimb
    array_c = ctypes.c_float * dima

    suma = array_a()
    sumb = array_b()
    sumc = array_c()

    inda = 0
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        for j in range(0, len(a[i])):
            suma[inda] = a[i][j]
            inda = inda + 1
        indb = 0
    for i in range(0, len(b)):
        for j in range(0, len(b[i])):
            sumb[indb] = b[i][j]
            indb = indb + 1

    libmatmult.matmult(ctypes.byref(suma), ctypes.byref(sumb), ctypes.byref(sumc), 2);

    res = numpy.zeros([len(a), len(a)])
    indc = 0
    for i in range(0, len(sumc)):
        res[indc][i % len(a)] = sumc[i]
        if i % len(a) == len(a) - 1:
            indc = indc + 1

    return res
```

I would have bet that the version using C would have been faster ... and I'd have lost ! Below is my benchmark which seems to show that I either did it incorrectly, or that `numpy` is stupidly fast:

[image: benchmark]

I'd like to understand why the `numpy` version is faster than the `ctypes` version, I'm not even talking about the pure Python implementation since it is kind of obvious.

Comment: Nice question - it turns out np.dot() is also faster than a naive GPU implementation in C.

Comment: One of the biggest things making your naive C matmul slow is the memory access pattern.  `b[k * n + j];` inside the inner loop (over `k`) has a stride of `n`, so it touches a different cache line on every access.  And your loop can't auto-vectorize with SSE/AVX.  **Solve this by transposing `b` up-front, which costs O(n^2) time and pays for itself in reduced cache misses while you do O(n^3) loads from `b`.**  That would still be a naive implementation without cache-blocking (aka loop tiling), though.

Comment: Since you use an `int sum` (for some reason...), your loop could actually vectorize without `-ffast-math` if the inner loop was accessing two sequential arrays.  FP math is not associative, so compilers can't re-order operations without `-ffast-math`, but integer math is associative (and has lower latency than FP addition, which helps if you're not going to optimize your loop with multiple accumulators or other latency hiding stuff).  `float` -> `int` conversion costs about the same as an FP `add` (actually using the FP add ALU on Intel CPUs), so it's not worth it in optimized code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Numpy, but the source is on Github.  Part of dot products are implemented in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c.src, which I'm assuming is translated into specific C implementations for each datatype.  For example:

```
/**begin repeat
 *
 * #name = BYTE, UBYTE, SHORT, USHORT, INT, UINT,
 * LONG, ULONG, LONGLONG, ULONGLONG,
 * FLOAT, DOUBLE, LONGDOUBLE,
 * DATETIME, TIMEDELTA#
 * #type = npy_byte, npy_ubyte, npy_short, npy_ushort, npy_int, npy_uint,
 * npy_long, npy_ulong, npy_longlong, npy_ulonglong,
 * npy_float, npy_double, npy_longdouble,
 * npy_datetime, npy_timedelta#
 * #out = npy_long, npy_ulong, npy_long, npy_ulong, npy_long, npy_ulong,
 * npy_long, npy_ulong, npy_longlong, npy_ulonglong,
 * npy_float, npy_double, npy_longdouble,
 * npy_datetime, npy_timedelta#
 */
static void
@name@_dot(char *ip1, npy_intp is1, char *ip2, npy_intp is2, char *op, npy_intp n,
           void *NPY_UNUSED(ignore))
{
    @out@ tmp = (@out@)0;
    npy_intp i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++, ip1 += is1, ip2 += is2) {
        tmp += (@out@)(*((@type@ *)ip1)) *
               (@out@)(*((@type@ *)ip2));
    }
    *((@type@ *)op) = (@type@) tmp;
}
/**end repeat**/
```

This appears to compute one-dimensional dot products, i.e. on vectors.  In my few minutes of Github browsing I was unable to find the source for matrices, but it's possible that it uses one call to `FLOAT_dot` for each element in the result matrix.  That means the loop in this function corresponds to your inner-most loop.

One difference between them is that the "stride" -- the difference between successive elements in the inputs -- is explicitly computed once before calling the function.  In your case there is no stride, and the offset of each input is computed each time, e.g. `a[i * n + k]`.  I would have expected a good compiler to optimise that away to something similar to the Numpy stride, but perhaps it can't prove that the step is a constant (or it's not being optimised).

Numpy may also be doing something smart with cache effects in the higher-level code that calls this function.  A common trick is to think about whether each row is contiguous, or each column -- and try to iterate over each contiguous part first.  It seems difficult to be perfectly optimal, for each dot product, one input matrix must be traversed by rows and the other by columns (unless they happened to be stored in different major order).  But it can at least do that for the result elements.

Numpy also contains code to choose the implementation of certain operations, including "dot", from different basic implementations.  For instance it can use a [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) library.  From discussion above it sounds like CBLAS is used.  This was translated from Fortran into C.  I think the implementation used in your test would be the one found in here: http://www.netlib.org/clapack/cblas/sdot.c.

Note that this program was written by a machine for another machine to read.  But you can see at the bottom that it's using an unrolled loop to process 5 elements at a time:

```
for (i = mp1; i <= *n; i += 5) {
stemp = stemp + SX(i) * SY(i) + SX(i + 1) * SY(i + 1) + SX(i + 2) * 
    SY(i + 2) + SX(i + 3) * SY(i + 3) + SX(i + 4) * SY(i + 4);
}
```

This unrolling factor is likely to have been picked after profiling several.  But one theoretical advantage of it is that more arithmetical operations are done between each branch point, and the compiler and CPU have more choice about how to optimally schedule them to get as much instruction pipelining as possible.

Comment: I was wrong again, it looks like the routines in Numpy under `/linalg/blas_lite.c` are called. the first `daxpy_` is the unrolled inner loop for dot products on floats, and is based on code from a LONG time ago. Check out the comment there: *"constant times a vector plus a vector. uses unrolled loops for increments equal to one. jack dongarra, linpack, 3/11/78. modified 12/3/93, array(1) declarations changed to array(\*)"*

Comment: My guess is neither of these algorithms are actually used for floats, doubles, single complex, or double complex. NumPy requires ATLAS, which has its own versions of `daxpy` and `dgemm`. There are versions for float and complex; for integers and such, NumPy probably falls back on the C template you've linked.

Answer (score 42):

NumPy uses a highly-optimized, carefully-tuned BLAS method for matrix multiplication (see also: [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/)). The specific function in this case is GEMM (for generic matrix multiplication). You can look up the original by searching for `dgemm.f` (it's in Netlib).

The optimization, by the way, goes beyond compiler optimizations. Above, Philip mentioned Coppersmith–Winograd. If I remember correctly, this is the algorithm which is used for most cases of matrix multiplication in ATLAS (though a commenter notes it could be Strassen's algorithm).

In other words, your `matmult` algorithm is the trivial implementation. There are faster ways to do the same thing.

Comment: By the way, `np.show_config()` shows what lapack / blas it's linked to.

Comment: You and Philip make the right point (the problem is that the OP's implementation is slow), but I would guess that NumPy uses Strassen's algorithm or some variant rather than Coppersmith-Winograd, which has such large constants that it's usually not useful in practice.

Comment: Numpy use a BLAS library internally. It is OpenBLAS by default on most platforms (based on GotoBLAS). OpenBLAS does not use the Strassen algorithm based on my understanding of the code (same for the BLIS library). Strassen can be faster for very large matrices if implemented very carefully. That being said, it is not as numerically stable as the standard tile-based method. OpenBLAS makes use of multiple threads and SIMD instructions.

Answer (score 9):

The language used to implement a certain functionality is a bad measure of performance by itself. Often, using a more suitable algorithm is the deciding factor.

In your case, you're using the naive approach to matrix multiplication as taught in school, which is in O(n^3). However, you can do much better for certain kinds of matrices, e.g. square matrices, spare matrices and so on.

Have a look at the [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) (square matrix multiplication in O(n^2.3737)) for a good starting point on fast matrix multiplication. Also see the section "References", which lists some pointers to even faster methods.

For a more earthy example of astonishing performance gains, try to write a fast `strlen()` and compare it to the glibc implementation. If you don't manage to beat it, read glibc's `strlen()` source, it has fairly good comments.

Comment: +1 For using the big-oh notation and the analysis (I always remember the naive method n^3 vs Strassen alg with is about n^2.8). Again, the good way to check the speed of an alg is big-oh, not the language.

Comment: Probably more important in this case, the OP's naive C matmul isn't cache-blocked, and doesn't even transpose one of the inputs.  It loops over rows in one matrix and columns in the other, when they're both in row-major order, so it gets massive cache misses.   (A transpose is O(n^2) work up front to make the row*column vector dot products do sequential accesses, which also lets them auto-vectorize with SSE/AVX/whatever if you use `-ffast-math`.)

Comment: Using the Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm is not a good idea because it has a huge hidden constant factor. In fact, AFAIK, this is why no mainstream highly-optimized BLAS library use it. Not to mention it is complex to implement is not friendly to modern processor architectures. It is only useful for really HUGE matrices (too big for most practical problems). However Strassen is actually used in some BLAS libraries. Still, it is only used for relatively big matrices like >512x512 ones. In practice, a significant speed up from using Strassen is only visible for matrices like >4096x4096.

Answer (score 5):

The people who wrote NumPy obviously know what they're doing.

There are many ways to optimize matrix multiplication. For example, order you traverse the matrix affects the memory access patterns, which affect performance.
Good use of SSE is another way to optimize, which NumPy probably employs.
There may be more ways, which the developers of NumPy know and I don't.

BTW, did you compile your C code with optiomization?

You can try the following optimization for C. It does work in parallel, and I suppose NumPy does something along the same lines.
NOTE: Only works for even sizes. With extra work, you can remove this limitation and keep the performance improvement.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j+=2) {
            int sub1 = 0, sub2 = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                sub1 = sub1 + a[i * n + k] * b[k * n + j];
                sub1 = sub1 + a[i * n + k] * b[k * n + j + 1];
            }
            c[i * n + j]     = sub;
            c[i * n + j + 1] = sub;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried with different levels of optimization at compilation but that didn't change the result much compared to numpy

Comment: A good multiplication implementation would beat any optimization level. I'd guess that no optimization at all would be significantly worse.

Comment: This answer makes a lot of assumptions about what Numpy does. However, it does hardly any of them out of the box, offloading the work to a BLAS library instead when that is available. Performance of matrix multiplication depends heavily on the BLAS implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Numpy is also highly optimized code. There is an essay about parts of it in the book [Beautiful Code](http://books.google.com/books?id=gJrmszNHQV4C&q=numpy#v=snippet&q=numpy&f=false).

The ctypes has to go through a dynamic translation from C to Python and back that adds some overhead. In Numpy most matrix operations are done completely internal to it.

Comment: Numpy isn't itself optimized code. It *makes use of* optimized code, e.g., ATLAS.

Answer (score 3):

The most common reason given for Fortran's speed advantage in numerical code, afaik, is that the language makes it easier to detect [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) - the compiler can tell that the matrices being multiplied don't share the same memory, which can help improve caching (no need to be sure results are written back immediately into "shared" memory).  This is why C99 introduced [restrict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict).

However, in this case, I wonder if also the numpy code is managing to use some [special instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586609/using-sse-instructions#586670) that the C code is not (as the difference seems particularly large).