# What is the fastest way to compute sum of weighted products between columns?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
np.random.seed([3, 14])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
df

          A         B         C
0 -0.602923 -0.402655  0.302329
1 -0.524349  0.543843  0.013135
2 -0.326498  1.385076 -0.132454
3 -0.407863  1.302895 -0.604236
4 -0.243362 -0.211261 -2.056621
```

What is the fastest way to compute `df.A * 1 + df.B * 2 + df.C * 3`?

Essentially, I want, for this dataframe:

```
0   -0.501247
1    0.602741
2    2.046290
3    0.385219
4   -6.835748
```

The answer *cannot* be `df.A * 1 + df.B * 2 + df.C * 3` since the number of columns must not be hardcoded. So, I'd want  to compute `df.iloc[:, 0] * 1 + df.iloc[:, 1] * 2, ....` somehow.

I'd be interested in any `numba` solutions out there too!

Comment: I think `numpy` as the fastest dot product algorithm and I don`t think numba can beat that.

Comment: @Bharathshetty I certainly believe so. That could be why no one has bothered to come near this question :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

The fastest, to my knowledge, would be using `df.dot`.

```
df.dot((np.arange(df.shape[1]) + 1).reshape(-1, 1))

          0
0 -0.501247
1  0.602741
2  2.046290
3  0.385219
4 -6.835748
```

---

**Option 2**

Element wise product and `sum` along first axis

```
(df * (np.arange(df.shape[1]) + 1)).sum(1)

0   -0.501246
1    0.602742
2    2.046292
3    0.385219
4   -6.835747
```

---

**Performance**

### Small (*`5 x 3`*)

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 131 µs per loop  # dot
1000 loops, best of 3: 531 µs per loop   # element-wise prod + sum
```

### Large (*`100000 x 1000`*)

```
10 loops, best of 3: 36.4 ms per loop   # dot
1 loop, best of 3: 1.18 s per loop      # element-wise prod + sum
```

---

For information on the magic behind the implementation of `pandas`/`numpy`'s `dot` function, you may look at [Why is matrix multiplication faster with numpy than with ctypes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442365/why-is-matrix-multiplication-faster-with-numpy-than-with-ctypes-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

I try improve solution - remove reshape and change `arrange`:

```
a = df.dot(np.arange(1, len(df.columns)+1))
print (a)
0   -0.501247
1    0.602741
2    2.046290
3    0.385219
4   -6.835748
dtype: float64
```

Same in `numpy`:

```
a = pd.Series(np.dot(df.values, np.arange(1, len(df.columns)+1)), index=df.index)
print (a)
0   -0.501247
1    0.602741
2    2.046290
3    0.385219
4   -6.835748
dtype: float64
```

Comment: First solution: `36.3ms`, Second solution: `36.5 ms` on large data. I am surprised that Series constructor is so cheap.

Comment: Maybe is necessary test in large data - 100k * 100k

Comment: 100k is a lot of columns... possibility of overflow during calculation.

Comment: It was only idea, no problem ;)

Comment: Yeah... I can understand... I originally planned to test on 100k * 100k but when generating the data my computer became unresponsive... maybe you can test it? But I'm sure it will overflow.

Comment: I use working PC with win and 4GB RAM ;), But I can check the largest df as possible ;)

Comment: I have a 8gig mac, but it's over 4 years old... let me know how it goes!

Comment: I think my test are tottaly useless for `[1000000 rows x 1000 columns]` I get `In [2]: %timeit df.dot(np.arange(1, len(df.columns)+1))
1 loop, best of 3: 21 s per loop`, `In [5]: %timeit df.dot((np.arange(df.shape[1]) + 1).reshape(-1, 1))
1 loop, best of 3: 27 s per loop`

Comment: Wow... that's a crazy difference, considering the only change is the +1. :D

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts. You have my upvote :-)