# Fastest way to compute weighted sum of dataframe across rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have a dataframe with some columns. I'd like to apply some transformation to one column and use it as a weight for computing a weighted sum of the other columns. The issue is the way I'm doing it is currently taking too long. **Is there a faster way to do this?**

I'm currently calculating a new column, transposing, and using `df.dot` as suggested by [almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419962) [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980468) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112251). The issue is that I have an *extremely* large dataframe and so this method is taking a long time.

For example, given the following df

```
col1  col2  col3
 0.1   0.2   0.3
 1.4   1.5   1.6
 1.9   1.8   1.7
```

I create a new column, weights, that is `1/col3`

```
col1  col2  col3  weight
 0.1   0.2   0.3   3.333
 1.4   1.5   1.6   0.625
 1.9   1.8   1.7   0.588
```

and then I transpose and `df.dot` against the weight to get

```
col1  col2
2.32  2.66
```

Comment: How large is your dataframe?

Comment: Try to insert column into np.array. Not df['column_name], but np.array(df['column_name])

Comment: @IvanVnucec about 2,000,000,000x600 although I've split it up into dfs of 70000x600 for hopefully faster calculation

Answer (score 0):

I check linked answers and there is not used [`np.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), but [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html), I hope [this should be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442365/why-is-matrix-multiplication-faster-with-numpy-than-with-ctypes-in-python), but if use large DataFrames without huge RAM, it should be still slow:

```
w = 1 / df.col3
arr = np.dot(df.to_numpy().T, w.to_numpy())

df1 = pd.DataFrame([arr], columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
      col1     col2  col3
0  2.32598  2.66299   3.0
```

Comment: that was a typo - I meant `df.dot`