# Speed up Cython implementation of dot product multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, performance, cython

I'm trying to learn cython by trying to outperform Numpy at dot product operation `np.dot(a,b)`. But my implementation is about 4x slower.

So, this is my hello.pyx file cython implementation:

```
cimport numpy as cnp
cnp.import_array()

cpdef double dot_product(double[::1] vect1, double[::1] vect2):
    cdef int size = vect1.shape[0]
    cdef double result = 0
    cdef int i = 0
    while i < size:
        result += vect1[i] * vect2[i]
        i += 1
    return result
```

This is my .py test file:

```
import timeit

setup = '''
import numpy as np
import hello

n = 10000
a = np.array([float(i) for i in range(n)])
b = np.array([i/2 for i in a])
'''
lf_code = 'res_lf = hello.dot_product(a, b)'
np_code = 'res_np = np.dot(a,b)'
n = 100
lf_time = timeit.timeit(lf_code, setup=setup, number=n) * 100
np_time = timeit.timeit(np_code, setup=setup, number=n) * 100

print(f'Lightning fast time: {lf_time}.')
print(f'Numpy time: {np_time}.')
```

Console output:

```
Lightning fast time: 0.12186000000156127.
Numpy time: 0.028800000001183435.
```

Command to build hello.pyx:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

# define an extension that will be cythonized and compiled
ext = Extension(name="hello", sources=["hello.pyx"], include_dirs=[np.get_include()])
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

Processor:
i7-7700T @ 2.90 GHz

Comment: You are competing with [OpenBLAS](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS) (or similar): numpy only wraps this computation. Maybe you have been too ambitious. OpenBLAS and co. has CPU-arch specific kernels, SIMD, multithreading and  assembler code.

Comment: I don't think you can do better than numpy, but the challenge is nice. Numpy uses vector instructions which are supposed to work on multiple numbers at the same time. By the way using loop isn't the fatest way to do matrice multiplication. I suggest you to look at Strassen and Coppersmith algorithm. If you want to do better than numpy, use graphic card; Numba cuda is pretty well to do parallele computation without effort.

Comment: You aren’t first to try and fail: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10442365/5769463 cython is even harder than c, because cython can generate c code which is not easy to optimize

Comment: For what it's worth, being *only* factor 4 slower than OpenBLAS means that you probably did as well as you could without going to extreme measures.

Comment: @Neofelis (and @ead) This is *not* a matrix multiplication but a dot product. Thus,  Strassen and Coppersmith algorithms are not relevant here. Moreover, no, a GPU will not be faster for such a task because the array is too small. The latency to execute a kernel on the GPU is generally higher than this time (and GPU are optimized for big workload, clearly not low latency). Not to mention data transfer to the GPU are slow and this operation is known to be generally memory bound (like all BLAS level 1 primitives).

Comment: Did you enabled compiler optimizations? Can you please share the command line used to build the Cython module? Can you also provide the type of processor used to make the bench (eg. i5-9600KF) and update the question accordingly?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks, edited.

Comment: At very least you haven't set the `boundschecking` and `wraparound` compiler directives that can make array access significantly quicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem mainly comes from the lack of SIMD instructions** (due to both the bound-checking and the inefficient default compiler flags) compared to Numpy (which use OpenBLAS on most platforms by default).

To fix that, you should first add the following line in the beginning of the `hello.pix` file:

```py
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False
```

Then, you should use this new `setup.py` file:

```py
from distutils.core import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

# define an extension that will be cythonized and compiled
ext = Extension(name="hello", sources=["hello.pyx"], include_dirs=[np.get_include()], extra_compile_args=['-O3', '-mavx', '-ffast-math'])
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

Note that the flags are dependent of the compiler. That being said, both Clang and GCC support them (and probably ICC too). `-O3` tells Clang and GCC to use more aggressive optimization like the automatic vectorization of the code. `-mavx` tells them to use the AVX instruction set (which is only available on relatively recent x86-64 processors). `-ffast-math` tells them to assume that floating-point number operations are associative (which is not the case) and that you only use finite/basic numbers (no NaN, nor infinities). If the above assumption are not fulfilled, then the program can crash at runtime, so *be careful* about such flags.

Note that OpenBLAS automatically selects the instruction set based on your machine and AFAIK it does not use `-ffast-math` but a safer (low-level) alternative.

---

### Results:

Here are results on my machine:

```
Before optimization:
  Lightning fast time: 0.10018469997703505.
  Numpy time: 0.024747799989199848.

After (with GCC):
  Lightning fast time: 0.02865879996534204.
  Numpy time: 0.02456870001878997.

After (with Clang):
  Lightning fast time: 0.01965239998753532.
  Numpy time: 0.024799799984975834.
```

The code produced by Clang is **faster than Numpy** on my machine.

---

### Under the hood

An analysis of the assembly code executed by the processor on my machine show that the code only use slow scalar instruction, contains unnecessary bound-checks and is mainly limited by the `result += ...` operation (because of a loop carried dependency).

```sh
162e3:┌─→movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbx+rax*8]  # Load 1 item
162e8:│  mulsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rsi+rax*8]  # Load 1 item
162ed:│  addsd  xmm1,xmm0                   # Main bottleneck (accumulation)
162f1:│  cmp    rdi,rax
162f4:│↓ je     163f8                       # Bound checking conditional jump
162fa:│  cmp    rdx,rax
162fd:│↓ je     16308                       # Bound checking conditional jump
162ff:│  add    rax,0x1
16303:├──cmp    rcx,rax
16306:└──jne    162e3
```

Once optimized, the result is:

```sh
13720:┌─→vmovupd      ymm3,YMMWORD PTR [r13+rax*1+0x0]    # Load 4 items
13727:│  vmulpd       ymm0,ymm3,YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax*1]   # Load 4 items
1372c:│  add          rax,0x20
13730:│  vaddpd       ymm1,ymm1,ymm0        # Still a bottleneck (but better)
13734:├──cmp          rdx,rax
13737:└──jne          13720
```

The `result += ...` operation is still the bottleneck in the optimized version but this is much better since the loop work on 4 items at once. To remove the bottleneck, the loop must be partially unrolled. However, GCC (which is the default compiler on my machine) is not able to do that properly (even when ask to using `-funrol-loops` (due to a loop-carried dependency). This is why OpenBLAS should be a bit faster than the code produced by GCC.

Hopefully, Clang is able to do that by default. Here is the code produced by Clang:

```sh
59e0:┌─→vmovupd      ymm4,YMMWORD PTR [rax+rdi*8]       # load 4 items
59e5:│  vmovupd      ymm5,YMMWORD PTR [rax+rdi*8+0x20]  # load 4 items
59eb:│  vmovupd      ymm6,YMMWORD PTR [rax+rdi*8+0x40]  # load 4 items
59f1:│  vmovupd      ymm7,YMMWORD PTR [rax+rdi*8+0x60]  # load 4 items
59f7:│  vmulpd       ymm4,ymm4,YMMWORD PTR [rbx+rdi*8]
59fc:│  vaddpd       ymm0,ymm4,ymm0
5a00:│  vmulpd       ymm4,ymm5,YMMWORD PTR [rbx+rdi*8+0x20]
5a06:│  vaddpd       ymm1,ymm4,ymm1
5a0a:│  vmulpd       ymm4,ymm6,YMMWORD PTR [rbx+rdi*8+0x40]
5a10:│  vmulpd       ymm5,ymm7,YMMWORD PTR [rbx+rdi*8+0x60]
5a16:│  vaddpd       ymm2,ymm4,ymm2
5a1a:│  vaddpd       ymm3,ymm5,ymm3
5a1e:│  add          rdi,0x10
5a22:├──cmp          rsi,rdi
5a25:└──jne          59e0
```

The code is not optimal (because it should unroll the loop at least 6 times due to the latency of the `vaddpd` instruction), but it is very good.

Comment: The "Under the hood" section is great. I have little to no knowledge of ASM, so it's always a pleasure to learn. Makes me want to disregard the "the compiler is better than you" thing and try writing ASM.